# Strange error created Devise User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have created devise users many times but this is the first this that this has happened. where Devise would fail to create the files it creates.  I am not sure why.

```
rails generate devise user
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20150424115858_devise_create_users.rb
      create    app/models/user.rb
      invoke    rspec
      create      spec/models/user_spec.rb
      invoke      fabrication
/Users/moiseszaragoza/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec': PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Here is a copy of my config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    initializer 'setup_asset_pipeline', :group => :all  do |app|
      app.config.assets.precompile.shift
      app.config.assets.precompile.push(Proc.new do |path|
        File.extname(path).in? [
          '.html', '.erb', '.haml',                 # Templates
          '.png',  '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg',         # Images
          '.eot',  '.otf', '.svc', '.woff', '.ttf', # Fonts
        ]
      end)
    end
    I18n.enforce_available_locales = false
    config.before_initialize do
      dev = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'config.yml')
      YAML.load(File.open(dev)).each do |key,value|
      ENV[key.to_s] = value
      end if File.exists?(dev)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you provide your config/application.rb?

Comment: @AlexanderKobelev the config/application.rb file is now as past of the question

Answer (score 3):

It seems a problem with your database, have you configure database.xml yet? if so try a different version of the devise gem, update it and if it's the last version, downgrade.

Comment: I don't have a database.xml I have a config/database.yml

Comment: This is a guess, not a definitive answer. You should first discuss the question in the comment area, then post an answer once you're sure that you've solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be exploding on invoking fabrication, since I don't have the users table yet.

I removed `gem 'fabrication-rails'` from my gem file and then it worked

```
$ rails generate devise user
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20150424130126_devise_create_users.rb
      create    app/models/user.rb
      invoke    rspec
      create      spec/models/user_spec.rb
      invoke      factory_girl
      create        spec/factories/users.rb
      insert    app/models/user.rb
       route  devise_for :users
```